# How to add php date() and variable in wp shortcode?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to create a shortcode in wordpress. User just input their company name and the result will be "Copyright 2013 Agency Name". I have just used the following code

```
 function copyright_shortcode($atts){
extract(shortcode_atts(array(
    'company' => 'Your company name' 


    ),$atts,'copyright'));

$text='&copy;<span class="small"> Copyright '.date('Y') $company.'</span>';


return $text;
}
add_shortcode('copyright','copyright_shortcode');
```

But it is showing a syntax error. I think, it is very simple problem. Please tell me the solution.

Comment: General tip: if you get an error message, TELL US what the error message is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one syntax error I spotted is you need a . before $company

```
$text='&copy;<span class="small"> Copyright '.date('Y') . $company.'</span>';
```